# How to get TempData in an integration test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing

I have a controller with the following actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route(
    "/MyShop/OrderDetails/CancelOrder", 
    Name = UrlRouteDefinitions.MyShopOrderDetailsCancelOrder)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult CancelOrder(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
    var isCancelSuccessful = _orderBusinessLogic.CancelOrderById(viewModel.Order.Id);

    if (isCancelSuccessful)
    {
        //to show a success-message after the redirect
        this.TempData["SuccessCancelOrder"] = true;
    }

    return RedirectToRoute(UrlRouteDefinitions.MyShopOrderDetailsIndex, new
    {
        orderId = viewModel.Order.Id
    });
}
```

Then I also have the following piece of HTML in the View for the Controller mentioned above:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @if (TempData["SuccessCancelOrder"] != null) 
    {
        //show the message
        @TempData["SuccessCancelOrder"].ToString();
    }
</div>
```

Now I'm writing an integration test (code-summary below) to check if the `CancelOrder()` method works as expected. There I'd like to access the value of the `TempData` dictionary to check its correctness.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    try
    {
        //Arrange: create an Order with some Products
        var orderId = CreateFakeOrder();

        //Open the Order Details page for the arranged Order
        var httpRequestMessage = base.PrepareRequest(
            HttpMethod.Get,
            "/MyShop/OrderDetails?orderId=" + orderId,
            MediaTypeEnum.Html);

        var httpResponse    = base.Proxy.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
        var responseContent = httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var viewModel       = base.GetModel<MyViewModel>(responseContent);

        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, httpResponse.StatusCode);


        //Try to execute a POST to cancel the Order
        httpRequestMessage = base.PrepareRequest(
            HttpMethod.Post,
            "/MyShop/OrderDetails/CancelOrder",
            MediaTypeEnum.Html,
            httpResponse, content: viewModel);


        httpResponse = base.Proxy.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
        var expectedRedirectLocation = $"{this.RelativeHomeUrl}/MyShop/OrderDetails?orderId=" + orderId;
        var receivedRedirectLocation = WebUtility.UrlDecode(httpResponse.Headers.Location.ToString());


        //we expect that the Order Details page will be reloaded 
        //with the ID of the already cancelled Order
        Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.Redirect, httpResponse.StatusCode);

        //-----------------------------------------------------------
        //here I'm going to re-execute a GET-request 
        //on the Order Details page. 
        //
        //Then I need to check the content of the message 
        //that's been written in the TempData
        //-----------------------------------------------------------
    }
    finally
    {
        //delete the arranged data
    }
}
```

In any case, I don't know how to access it from my integration test. Does anybody know how to do it and if there's a way at all?

Answer (score 8):

`Controller.TempData` is public so you can easily access it and check if your key/value exists

```
[TestMethod]
public void TempData_Should_Contain_Message() {    
    // Arrange
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
    var controller = new TestController();
    controller.TempData = tempData;

    // Act
    var result = controller.DoSomething();

    //Assert
    controller.TempData["Message"]
        .Should().NotBeNull()
        .And.BeEquivalentTo("Hello World");

}
```

Comment: yes, that's true, but wouldn't this be a unit test since you're instantiating the controller and executing the actions? what i'm doing in my integration test is sending HttpRequestMessage objects to the various endpoints of the application and checking the obtained HttpResponseMessage objects

Comment: I know that this is a unit test. Was meant to show access to the property is possible. You did not provide a [mcve] in your OP so I was not about to guess how your test is exercised.